# How to Use QThread In PySide6

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

How can I run multithreading in PySide6, for pure python I use:

```
import threading
t = threading.Thread(target=My_Target)
t.start()
```

but for [QThread](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QThread.html) if I want to do the same, the code will look like?